# DbContext Transient makes Insert/Add no more working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I just set my DbContext Lifetime to `Transient` to get rid of `"A second operation started on this context ..."` (I don't know why this error occurred bc I await all async-calls

But now with Transient DbContext I can't insert a new Entity into my database.
It just gives me this error:

```
MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Duplicate entry '2' for key 'backgrounds.PRIMARY'
```

```
public class Character
    {
        public int CharacterId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
        public int RaceId { get; set; }
        public int ClassId { get; set; }
        public int BackgroundId { get; set; }
    }
```

---

**In detail:**

And on the webpage the user can select a Class, Race and Background (Dungeons & Dragons)

So firstly I create a new Character object without any properties set. (`new Character()`)

After that the User can select a backgriund and I do: `Character.Background = SelectedBackground`

After the user selected Race, Class and Background I call my Create method of my repository:

```
public async Task<TEntity> CreateAsync(TEntity entity){
        _set.Add(entity);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return entity;
    }
```

where `TEntity` is `Character` and `_set` is `DbSet<Character>`

But this Create method gives me the error above.

Character and Background table:

[image: Character and Background table]

Comment: *I don't know why this error occurred* - because a second operation started on that same instance. If you really have reliably awaited it's probably not your one thread X doing it twice, it's probably two different threads serving eg concurrent requests or something..

Comment: *Duplicate entry '2' for key* - sounds like the context doesn't realize that the background exists because you're setting a character.background to instance of background it's never seen. Do `Character.BackgroundId = SelectedBackground.BackgroundId` or similar "set the id property, not the navigation object "

Comment: @CaiusJard thank you for your answer. Using the BackgroudId gives me the next error (see edit) 

Concerning the two operations on DbContext ist strange because it worked fine before I moved me CreationSteps (choose Class, Race, Background) into single Blazor components.

Comment: I was going to ask if this was Blazor(Server) - if it is, you should be aware that working with EF's contexts requires some slightly different treatment - you can't just whack a per-request context in because the requests are actually much long-lived than the context is designed to be, and Transient isn't the solution either. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-6.0 for more advice. I use the contextfactory to make my BSS contexts whenever I have a unit of work to do

Comment: Oh yeah, I should have mentioned that it is a Blazor Server App but thank you very much!

Comment: @CaiusJard Maybe another question: In the page it tells me to use a ContextFactory and create new Context for each component. But how can I pass the new Context to my Repository/Service Layer. Using DI in Program.cs i have: `builder.Services.AddScoped<ICharacterRepository, CharacterRepository>();`

Comment: If possible, do not pass the context, pass the factory through constructor injection. Create context in repository, use 'using' block working on it and everything should be fine. 'Using' block is a must when using context factory, because context created by the factory must be manually disposed.

Comment: is there a cleaner way than putting an using block in every CRUD method in my repository?